# I am getting IMEI Number error in Android 10

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, imei

I am getting IMEI & SIM Serial Number error in Android 10,
Exceptions are -

```
java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: The user 10526 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.
java.lang.SecurityException: getIccSerialNumber: The user 10526 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.
```

Comment: Post  your code, so we can help, did you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> in manifest ?

Comment: showing permission only granted to the system apps

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting IMEI & SIM Serial Number error in Android 10

From Android 10, Google added restriction to access the device's non-resettable identifiers.

All methods [getImei()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getImei(int)), [getDeviceId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getDeviceId(int)), [getSerial()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build#getSerial()) will return **SecurityException** or **null** for all Third-party apps(installed from Google play store).

Not possible to get IMEI on Android 10 or higher devices.

See [Restriction on non-resettable device identifiers](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids)